# Automatic Weights Issues

Tags: rigging

I sculpted a hand and retoplogized it. I tried to rig the hand with the rigify rig, and for some reason, it didn't work. I tried making my own rig and it has the exact same problem. It's like the bones don't move the finger that they're in, and instead move the rest of the hand each. It's weird. It has to be a problem with the model, so I'd like to know how I can fix it.[image]

Blender file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/w0nnvo5d93w4528/Hand_Problems.....blend/file

Comment: Your hand has backward normals, which is why the autoweights aren't what you expected them to be.

Comment: thanks, man! I had no idea. Is recalculating inside the way to make my Normals facing the right way, or is it recalculating out? I'm used to 2.79, so I'm not familiar with those options.

Comment: UPDATE: YOU WERE RIGHT!!! I was losing my mind over this! I couldn't tell they were backward! It works now! How do I give you a badge or something?

Answer (score 0):

Foreword: you seem to have multiple rigs in your scene, none of which are named. This is the best way to get lost. Ideally you should name your things, and not have just one rig for the same character.

Two issues here: duplicated bones and weight paints.

Your metarig have lots of duplicated bones. Which lead Rigify to generate a rig with lots of duplicated parts, and when running automatic weights: duplicated deform bones fight for influence making a mess. I tried to find a way to delete duplicates in a simple manner, but I couldn't find one that didn't easily made the metarig unable tu re-generate a rig. So I would suggest you to delete all metarigs and rigs, and start the rigging from a clean new metarig.

Your weight painting is all messed up. I guess you used the automatic weights but didn't check the result afterward. Bits of your arms are assigned to jaw, chest and fingers bones, and the four arms bones weights aren't well spread on the mesh.

To fix this, <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into object mode. The manual boring way to cleanup vertex groups is to select an object, go under Properties Editor > Mesh Data tab > Vertex Groups panel, click the dorp down menu and click  `Delete All Groups` and repeat for each mesh object.
But since you have many objects to deal with, I made a script that does it for you. Just select all your objects that have weights, open the script editor, make a new empty script, paste the following and hit <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to run it.

```py
import bpy

# Get the selected objects
obs = bpy.context.selected_objects

# Iterate through selected objects
for ob in obs:
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        # Delete all vertex groups
        for group in ob.vertex_groups:
            try:
                ob.vertex_groups.remove(group)
            else:
                print(f"No vertex groups in '{ob.name}'")
            
        print(f"Deleted vertex groups from '{ob.name}'")
    else:
        print(f"Skipped non-mesh object '{ob.name}'")
```

Then, you should be able to run the automatic weights again and have it less problematic. But do <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into weight paint mode, enable Auto Normalize so that painting will take weights from other groups instead of adding new weights and make unwanted deformations:

[image]

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> over a mesh part to see and select the weights available where you clicked, and make sure only the needed bones affect the right places. Your biggest areas of concerns are the elbows and shoulders, so focus on that. There isn't any trick there, just paint till it works.